# Changing route doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a web page, I'm quite newbie using Angularjs. I've changed the architecture in order to use ng-view and move dynamically through the subpages. And when the route is /project nothing happens and moreover there is no error on the console.

In chrome when I inspect the element it appears as

```
<!-- ngView: -->
```

Thanks in advance.

**index.html:**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="innhomeweb">
...
<div ng-view></div>
```

**app.module.js:**

```
var Appmodule = angular.module('innhomeweb', [
'projectList',
'callList',
'organizationList',
'searchList',
'adminModule',
'transformModule',
'ngRoute',]);

Appmodule.config(['$locationProvider' ,'$routeProvider',
function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/project', {
        template: '<project-list></project-list>',

        controller: 'projectList'

    });
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago. Try adding `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` right before your `$routeProvider.when()` to configure the deep linking and `.otherwise('/project');` right after it to set the default path.

The AngularJS tutorial claims that "[setting a prefix is not necessary](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)", but I wasn't able to get it to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you specified a little strange `template` in `$routeProvider`, just try to replace it by, for example, `template: '<h1>TEST</h1>',` and it should work fine.

Comment: It does not work either. This template is the one that i was using before, i mean it works without the ng-view. Thanks anyways!